# Is there a way to stop TypeScript from creating JavaScript with 'require'

Tags: typescript

In my TypeScript, I'm importing a module as follows:

```
import swal from "sweetalert2";
```

When I compile the file to JavaScript, it outputs:

```
const sweetalert2_1 = require("sweetalert2");
```

Then I get a browser message:

```
'require is not defined'
```

Is there a way to get the JavaScript to compile without 'require'?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 2):

You can change this using the compiler option `--module` to target `ES6` or later:

```
tsc --module ES6
```

You can also do this in your .tsconfig file

```
"module": "ES6",
```

The result of this is that your import statement will transform from the TypeScript:

```
import { go } from './mod';
```

Into the JavaScript:

```
import { go } from './mod';
```

If you are using the browser native module loader, you may find that it expects the file extension:

```
import { go } from './mod.js';
```